# Uploading and image using PHP fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I’m trying to upload an image using the following code but it fails with the error (below). Can anyone tell me why?

```
<?php
include("mysqlconnect.php");

function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
{
  if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
  switch($imagetype)
  {
    case 'image/bmp':  return '.bmp';
    case 'image/gif':  return '.gif';
    case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
    case 'image/png':  return '.png';
    default:           return false;
  }
}

if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

  $file_name   = $_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
  $temp_name   = $_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
  $imgtype     = $_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
  $ext         = GetImageExtension($imgtype);
  $imagename   = date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
  $target_path = "images/".$imagename;

  if (move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {
    $query_upload = "INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES ('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";

    mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());  
  } else {
    exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
  } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement must begin like this

```
INSERT into `images_tbl`
```

Not

```
INSERT into 'images_tbl'
```

You must wrap the table name and column names in back-ticks (`) not in single quotes because wrapping inside single quotes is not a valid syntax. For more you can check the [manual of mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) which contains the description and syntaxes

Answer (score 0):

Try next

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl (images_path,submission_date) VALUES ('$target_path','$date')";
```

You're confusing ' with ` . But in this query you can do it without. Only put single quotes around values you want to insert.